# iOS Development: How do I auto match players in Game Center?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, gamekit, game-center

I have a "Play Now" button in my app that allows players to be auto-matched with other random players.  Maybe I'm missing this somewhere in the docs, but how do I write the code to auto match players?

The Game Center sandbox server has been messed up the last few days, so I'm having a hard time trying different things since I have to guess because the Game Kit docs aren't exactly clear on how to do this.  Currently, I have code setup (but untested) to create a match with a friend...

```
NSArray *playerList = [NSArray arrayWithObject:pid];
GKMatchRequest *request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
request.minPlayers = 2;
request.maxPlayers = 4;
request.playersToInvite = playerList;

[[self waitingIndicator] startAnimating];

[[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] findMatchForRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(GKMatch *match, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
    {
        //handle error
    }

    else if (match != nil)
    {
        self.myMatch = match;

        //start match code
    }
}];
```

But how do I auto match two random people looking for a game?  My guess, since the docs don't say it, or I'm missing it, is that in order to create an auto match, I simply set the `playersToInvite` property of the match object to nil?  If not, how do I create an auto match?

One other question, while we're on the topic, the Game Kit docs site a few common matchmaking scenarios, one of them being...

> A player can also create a network
>   match using the Game Center
>   application. When they invite a friend
>   into a multiplayer game, your
>   application is launched on both
>   devices, and each copy of your
>   application receives an invitation to
>   join the game.

But I can't figure out how to do this in the Game Center app for testing purposes.  How does a user create a network match using the Game Center app?  I don't see any buttons for that anywhere in the Game Center app.

Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: Same issue as Bob described below. My code used to work for both auto-matching and invites. Without introducing any changes, is only working with invitations but not auto-matching in the sandbox environment... If anybody has a solution, please let me know.

Comment: Same issue as Bob & DiegoR described below. My code used to work for both auto-matching and invites. Without introducing any changes, is only working with invitations but not auto-matching in the sandbox environment... If anybody has a solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, now that the sandbox Game Center server is back up, I was able to confirm that auto-matching works by setting the `playersToInvite` property to nil, or not setting it all.

Comment: Is this still working for you? I am having a problem in the last week where the auto-matching no longer works.  As far as I can see, nothing has changed in my code and inviting friends still works, but not auto-matching.  Also the code I am running that's already been released and works fine with the production Game Center servers does not work with the Sandbox.  Any clues?