# ios can players form teams of 2 and play other teams of 2 in game center

Tags: ios, game-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS Development: How do I auto match players in Game Center?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629203/ios-development-how-do-i-auto-match-players-in-game-center)
>   [How to split up players into teams on game center?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948255/how-to-split-up-players-into-teams-on-game-center)

I am trying to figure out if game center in the ios allows the matching system to create groups of two players each and have those teams of two play against other teams of two players.  Does anyone know if this is possible and if it is, is there a place where I can look to see how how it is done like a web page?  This would be a turn based game where two players in the team play together each turn.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks.  I see how to do a match but do not see how to do a match where I can group the players into teams of 2 and have them play as a team of 2 against other teams of 2 in the game center.

Comment: It's  also a duplicate of [How to split up players into teams on game center](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8948255/62576),  which doesn't have an answer after several months, so I'm  guessing that it's either worded very badly or no one knows.